# What is considered a good practice for loading data by user location? How do Yelp, Zillow, etc. get the user's general location information?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

Please forgive me if this is too general for stack overflow, but I'm curious to know how I can go to Yelp, Zillow, or any other sites which are driven by user location.

In my current app, I am using `navigator.geolocation` so it is front end driven:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    const currentPosition = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  /* set some values, handle error, etc. */
}
```

However, this can take some time.  In my case, after finding the user location I then load the google map on that particular location.

In the case when I go to yelp.com, it doesn't load on my current precise location but rather in my general area.  Sometimes it gets my area correct, but other times it is a metro area close to me.  In the case of other sites like Zillow, it will load the map on the whole region, like all of San Francisco and surrounding areas, or all of Los Angeles, etc.

How do those sites handle the initial location?  Is it something fancy server side, or is it something in the browser, or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think they are detecting your IP and then look it up where is the geolocation of the IP supposed to be. Here's an [example](https://www.iplocation.net/).

Comment: I guess so, or use 3rd party API such as ipinfo.io . example: `$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, "jsonp");`